# How to feed a struct in storage containing a dynamic array in solidity?

Tags: struct, solidity

How to feed a struct in storage containing a dynamic array in solidity ?
For example this code doesn't work. it returns
`UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Recipient memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.`

```js
struct Recipient {
    address target;
    uint256 amount;
}

struct Reward {
    uint256 timestamp;
    Recipient[] recipients;
}

contract Mwe {
    Reward reward;

    constructor() {
        Recipient[] memory recipients = new Recipient[](1);
        recipients[0] = Recipient(msg.sender, 1);
        reward.recipients = recipients;
        reward.timestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
}
```

How can I modify this code to adequately populate reward ?

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems this to be the right way.

```js
    constructor() {
        reward.timestamp = block.timestamp;
        reward.recipients.push(Recipient(msg.sender, 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may have discovered on Stack Overflow, in Solidity, **you cannot directly copy a dynamic array from memory to storage**. Instead, you need to push your data inside the dynamic storage array.

So doing this is correct:

```
constructor() {
    reward.timestamp = block.timestamp;
    reward.recipients.push(Recipient(msg.sender, 1));
}
```

If you have more recipients to add to the array, you can use a loop like this:

```
constructor() {
    Recipient[] memory recipients = new Recipient[](3);
    recipients[0] = Recipient(msg.sender, 1);
    recipients[1] = Recipient(address1, 1);
    recipients[2] = Recipient(address2, 1);
    reward.timestamp = block.timestamp;

    // Copy the dynamic array from memory to storage using a loop
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        reward.recipients.push(recipients[i]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare your recipients array inside the constructor as storage, and then your code will compile without problems:

```
constructor() {
    Recipient[] storage recipients = reward.recipients; // Here are the changes
    recipients[0] = Recipient(msg.sender, 1);
    reward.recipients = recipients;
    reward.timestamp = block.timestamp;
}
```

However, using the **push** method is generally considered the correct way to add elements to a dynamic array in Solidity.